# A definable set in $(\mathbb{R}, +,-,*,0,1,<)$ that is not definable without parameters.

Tags: model-theory

Consider the structure $(\mathbb{R},+,-,*,0,1,<)$. Can someone exhibit a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that is definable with parameters in that structure, but not definable without parameters?

Comment: Sounds like elimination of quantifiers could be relevant here, have you tried intervals like $(\pi,\infty)$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{R}$ be the field of real numbers. I claim that the parameter-freely-definable elements of $\mathcal{R}$ are exactly the algebraic reals; consequently, sets like $\{\pi\}$ are definable with parameters but are not definable without parameters.

The parameter-free-definability of the algebraic reals follows from elementary algebra. Suppose $f$ is a nonconstant polynomial with rational coefficients, and $a$ is a solution to $f(x)=0$. Since nonconstant polynomials have finite zero sets, there are rationals $p,q$ such that $a$ is the unique zero of $f$ in $(p,q)$. But each rational is obviously definable in $\mathcal{R}$, so "the unique zero of $f$ in $(p,q)$" is in fact a parameter-free definition of $a$ in $\mathcal{R}$.

The hard direction is the converse, and this is where model theory properly enters the picture. We know that [the theory of real closed fields admits quantifier elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field#Decidability_and_quantifier_elimination). It's easy to check that every real definable in $\mathcal{R}$ by a quantifier-and-parameter-free formula is in fact algebraic, so we're done. Alternatively, quantifier elimination implies [model completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_complete_theory), so since the algebraic reals are a real closed field we get by elementarity that every parameter-freely-definable element of $\mathcal{R}$ is algebraic.

Comment: Wait, what is the proof that the definable elements are the algebraic numbers? I find that a little hard to believe.

Comment: @user107952 It's a consequence of quantifier elimination (see the link in the first sentence). Think about what quantifier-free formulas you can write in the relevant language. By quantifier elimination, every definable element is in fact quantifier-freely definable.

Comment: @user107952 Alternatively, observe that the algebraic reals $\mathcal{A}$ are a real-closed field which is a substructure of $\mathcal{R}$. Since quantifier elimination implies [model-completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_complete_theory) (if you haven't seen this before it's a good exercise), this means that in fact $\mathcal{A}$ is an **elementary** substructure of $\mathcal{R}$. This means that every parameter-freely definable element of $\mathcal{R}$ is already an element of $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: @user107952 Note meanwhile that model-completeness is much weaker than quantifier elimination: it only gets you elimination down to *existential* formulas, rather than quantifier-free formulas. Whipping up a theory which is model-complete but doesn't admit full quantifier elimination is another good exercise.

Comment: Yes, I can see that only algebraic numbers are definable, but that doesn't imply all algebraic numbers are definable.

Comment: @user107952 That's actually the easier part. Suppose $f$ is a nonconstant polynomial with rational coefficients and $a$ is a solution to the equation $f(x)=0$. Since nonconstant polynomial equations have finitely many solutions, we can find rationals $p,q$ such that $a$ is the unique solution to $f(x)=0$ in $(p,q)$. But every rational is parameter-freely definable in $\mathcal{R}$, so "The unique solution to $f(x)=0$ in $(p,q)$" is itself a parameter-free definition of $a$ in $\mathcal{R}$. (Incidentally, note that this is the same trick used to show that all algebraic numbers are computable.)

Comment: @Noah: Or we can say "$r$ is the third root of $f(x)$" or the 17th root, you might find that more appealing...

Comment: @AsafKaragila Or that, indeed.

Comment: @user107952 I've edited to include the argument above.